# missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword Oracle trigger Error

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

**Everytime I run this trigger it gives this error:**
ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword

```
    create or replace trigger raise_error
    on CLIENT_PREFERENCE
    instead of insert
    for each row
    declare
    v_cid number;
     v_acid number;
     v_con varchar2(20);
      v_actname varchar2(20)
     begin
    select inserted.ClientNo,inserted.ActivityID into v_cid, v_acid
    from inserted

   select condition into v_con 
   from CCONDITION
   where ccondition.clientno=v_cid

   select Actname into v_actname
   from Activity
    where ActivityID=v_acid

   if v_con='Aquaphobia' and v_actname='Rafting'
    then
   print('ERROR!!!')
    end if;
    end
```

Relational Schema:

```
    CLIENT (ClientNo, Name, Sex, DOB, Address, Phone, Email, Occupation, MaritalStatus, Spouse, Anniversary) 
    CCONDITION (ClientNo, Condition)
    RESERVATION (ResNo, ResDate, NoOfGuests, StartDate, EndDate, ClientNo, Status) 
    ACTIVITY (ActivityID, ActName, ActDescription, ActRate, RiskLevel) 
    OUTDOOR_ACTIVITY (ActivityID) 
    INDOOR_ACTIVITY (ActivityID, Location, OpeningHours)
    ACCOMMODATION (RoomNo, LevelNo, AccStatus, ConnectedRoomNo, AccTypeID) 
    ACCOMMODATION_TYPE (AccTypeID, AccTypeName, AccTypeRate, NoOfBeds) 
    EQUIPMENT (EquipmentID, EquipName, Stock, NextInspection)
    SUPPLIER (BillerCode, BusinessName, ContactPerson, Phone)
    SUPPLIES (EquipmentID, BillerCode) 
    USES_EQUIPMENT (ActivityID, EquipmentID) CLIENT_PREFERENCE (ClientNo, ActivityID)
```

**Question:**

A Trigger which automatically raises an error whenever a client with Aqua phobia selects Rafting as a preferred outdoor activity.

Comment: [The syntax shown in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B) shows you have the clauses in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the right syntax using [CREATE TRIGGER syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B__BABBJHHG)

You are missing BEFORE/AFTER and INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE clauses:

```
create or replace trigger rasie_error
    "BEFORE | AFTER " "INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE"
    on CLIENT_PREFERENCE
```